# Xamarin.Forms - Set Height of ListView Cell On the Fly

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms MVVM project (in code, not XAML), and I have a ListView, where each cell is a different height (`HasUnevenRows = true`). Within each cell I want to be able to click a button and have some content added to or removed from the cell. I can do this, but the height of the cell does not adjust to the content until I scroll the item out of view and then back into view.

From what I've read online, it isn't possible to make the height of the cell automatically adjust to its content on the fly. So what I'm attempting next is to explicitly set the height of the cell on the fly.
In my current setup, I have 3 files:

- **MyPage.cs** - contains `var myListView = new ListView { HasUnevenRows = true, ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MyViewCell())`
- **MyViewCell.cs** - contains ViewCell template used in `myListView`, and the buttons, which I want to bind to a command in the view model in order to add content and explicitly change height of view cell.
- **MyViewModel.cs** - contains commands to add/remove content, and change height of view cell.

**Question:** From the View Model (MyViewModel.cs), how do I access a specific ViewCell in the ListView in order to change its height?

Answer (score 0):

Of the items that are bound to the ListView, have a property of height in the item model, and bind that to the ViewCell HeightRequest. You can then reference it that without any code in the View.

Comment: I tried doing that - from within my ViewCell constructor, I tried `this.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(ViewCell.HeightRequestProperty, model => model.ViewCellHeight);`, but it's saying ViewCell does not contain a definition for HeightRequestProperty...I also tried VisualElement.HeightRequestProperty, but then it crashes with an "invalid cast" error.